# Errors importing data using COPY comand at postgresql 9.3.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, csv

I am trying import a database table to Postgres 9.3.5 database server using COPY command as follows:

```
    COPY comment (generatedid, id, "timestamp", message, bugreport_id, personcontainer_id) FROM stdin;
    1   12840538    2010-03-03 09:50:46 How is that an error in HttpClient? Don&#39;t buffer large content in memory, or configure memory in your VM appropriately. HTTPCLIENT-922  102
    2   12841503    2010-03-04 21:36:13 Thanks for having a look!<br/><br/>I explored and found problem is with org.apache.james.mime4j.util.CharsetUtil of mime4j jar. It tries to load all available charset classes present under JVM.<br/><br/>I know memory for Perm Gen can be increased but there would be limit. I have increased it and would be doing a round of load testing. If it still consumes whole allocated space I would be putting some fix on CharsetUtil.<br/><br/>Stack trace for reference:<br/>-----------------------------------------<br/>java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at sun.nio.cs.ext.IBM970$Encoder.&lt;clinit&gt;(IBM970.java:2688)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at sun.nio.cs.ext.IBM970.newEncoder(IBM970.java:45)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.&lt;init&gt;(StringCoding.java:215)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.&lt;init&gt;(StringCoding.java:207)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:266)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:947)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at org.apache.james.mime4j.util.CharsetUtil.&lt;clinit&gt;(CharsetUtil.java:1028)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MIME.&lt;clinit&gt;(MIME.java:51)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.&lt;clinit&gt;(HttpMultipart.java:85)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartEntity.java:78)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.&lt;init&gt;(MultipartEntity.java:101)<br/><br/>  HTTPCLIENT-922  103
```

But I have errors in all data being imported (I put up only 2 rows of data above to show all errors of generally way) like:

> ```
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "}"
>     LINE 1: }<br/>&nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "break"
>     LINE 1: break;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/><br/>Recompiling after this change and trying again the...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ll"
>     LINE 1: ll provide a fix for CVS<br/>HEAD tomorrow. My apologies.<br...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Cookie"
>     LINE 1: Cookie&#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "headers"
>     LINE 1: headers only.<br/><br/>Oleg HTTPCLIENT-292 28066
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t had a chance to try this patch out, but if it works for yo...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s<br/>good enough for me.<br/><br/>Mike HTTPCLIENT-292 28068
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "d"
>     LINE 1: d feel better if someone else had a look.<br/><br/>Oleg HTTP...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ll"
>     LINE 1: ll try to come up with something more elegant for the 2.1 br...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t think either<br/>patch 2 or 3 handles this case, unless (i...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "What"
>     LINE 1: What we really need is a way to remove NTLM headers after th...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "authentication"
>     LINE 1: authentication has succeeded.<br/>Agreed. However, that stil...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/>if (&quot;NTLM&quot;.equalsIgnoreCase(authscheme.getSch...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "//"
>     LINE 1: // clean up<br/>}<br/><br/>As far as HEAD CVS goes, there ar...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t not<br/>pretty, but that appears to be the only option we ...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ll"
>     LINE 1: ll be working on a more elegant fix for the CVS HEAD<br/><br...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s the only real choice for 2.0.<br/><br/>Mike HTTPCLIENT-292...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "m"
>     LINE 1: m currently unable to test it and it could take a couple of ...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Digest"
>     LINE 1: Digest schemes still need to be refactored to take<br/>advan...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "code"
>     LINE 1: code&gt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "public"
>     LINE 1: public OutputStream getRequestOutputStream(boolean <br/>useC...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "/"
>     LINE 1: /code&gt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/><br/>The PutMethod does allow for chunking with the fun...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "code"
>     LINE 1: code&gt;
>     ^
>     unrecognized boolean value; assuming "on".
>     Showing only tuples.
>     \t: extra argument "Jun" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "00:39:55" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "GMT+00:00" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "20090)" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "seems" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "broken.<br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:150" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "SingleClientConnManager" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Get" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "connection" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "for" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "route" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "HttpRoute[{}-&gt;<a" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "href="http://www.seoconsultants.com">http://www.seoconsultants.com</a>]<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:334" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "ClientParamsStack" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "&#39;http.tcp.nodelay&#39;:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "true<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:335" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "ClientParamsStack" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "&#39;http.socket.buffer-size&#39;:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "8192<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:360" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "ClientParamsStack" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "&#39;http.protocol.version&#39;:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "HTTP/1.1<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:361" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "ClientParamsStack" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "&#39;http.useragent&#39;:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Mozilla/5.0" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "(Macintosh;" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "U;" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Intel" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Mac" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "OS" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "X" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "10.5;" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "en-US;" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "rv:1.9.0.10)" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Gecko/2009042315" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Firefox/3.0.10<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:362" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "RequestAddCookies" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CookieSpec" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "selected:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "best-match<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:362" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "DefaultClientConnection" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Connection" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "shut" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "down<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "2009/06/02" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "13:14:12:363" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "CEST" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "[DEBUG]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "SingleClientConnManager" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "-" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Releasing" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "connection" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$<a" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "href='mailto:ConnAdapter@3136e5'>ConnAdapter@3136e5</a><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[java]" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "Exception" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "in" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "thread" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "&quot;main&quot;" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "java.lang.ClassCastException:" ignored
>     \t: extra argument "org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeRegistry<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp [java]" ignored
>     invalid command \tat
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "conn"
>     LINE 1: conn.getRequestOutputStream((isHttp11() &amp;&amp; (null == ...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ve"
>     LINE 1: ve made something wrong in compilation process because the c...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "d"
>     LINE 1: d attached successfully works in production nowadays. HTTPCL...
>     ^
>     invalid command \
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ve"
>     LINE 1: ve tried to use your code. I downloaded the source code of H...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Roland"
>     LINE 1: Roland<br/> HTTPCLIENT-579 28761
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s not a problem for me to provide a totally functioning exam...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t attach example in this topic because it&#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s closed.<br/><br/>Just send me your emails in a private mes...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ll"
>     LINE 1: ll share the example.<br/> HTTPCLIENT-579 28762
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ve"
>     LINE 1: ve added a patch to the code you provided above to handle th...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Require"
>     LINE 1: Require NTLMv2 session security&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "is"
>     LINE 1: is set as an option inside &quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Network"
>     LINE 1: Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP base...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
>     LINE 1: .<br/><br/>The changes I made were a result of reading of: <...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "d"
>     LINE 1: d happily licence my change under the Apache Licence, I don&...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t believe it&#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s allowed as the original patch was under the LGPL.<br/><br/...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s request that we can create an external project (on sourcef...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "m"
>     LINE 1: m running the same issue like Zhao had.  What was the resolu...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s unclear about resolution &#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "Won"
>     LINE 1: Won&#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
>     LINE 1: t Fix &#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "?<"
>     LINE 1: ?<br/><br/>However, HttpClient 4.0 is capable of supporting ...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s not illegal. It&#39;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s just that you create a package that is probably no longer ...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s the reason why we cannot provide this out of the box. What...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s license terms you will need to check with a software licen...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "ve"
>     LINE 1: ve decided to attach complete example of integration Axis, H...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "d"
>     LINE 1: d recommend you before sending your requests to figure out h...
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
>     LINE 1: s the problem? HTTPCLIENT-579 28773
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "project"
>     LINE 1: project name=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "casau"
>     LINE 1: casau&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "default"
>     LINE 1: default=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "main"
>     LINE 1: main&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &gt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/>&nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &lt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "target"
>     LINE 1: target name=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "main"
>     LINE 1: main&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &gt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/>&nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &lt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "javac"
>     LINE 1: javac srcdir=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
>     LINE 1: .&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "destdir"
>     LINE 1: destdir=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
>     LINE 1: .&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "deprecation"
>     LINE 1: deprecation=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "yes"
>     LINE 1: yes&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "debug"
>     LINE 1: debug=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "yes"
>     LINE 1: yes&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/>&nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "classpath"
>     LINE 1: classpath=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near ".."
>     LINE 1: ../lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near ".."
>     LINE 1: ../lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near ".."
>     LINE 1: ../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0-ntlm-2.0.jar&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &gt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"
>     LINE 1: <br/>&nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &nbsp;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "&"
>     LINE 1: &lt;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "include"
>     LINE 1: include name=&quot;
>     ^
>     ERROR: syntax error at or near "**"
>     LINE 1: **/*.java&quot;/&gt;<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/javac&...
>   ^
> ```

How can I avoid these errors? Can I solve all errors using only one kind of change at the COPY command or in the data being imported?

Comment: Works here (after converting the spaces to tabs at the correct places)

Comment: How to do this conversion?@wildplasser

Comment: For your two sample rows, I did it by hand. For non-trivial amounts, you should first attempt to generate the correct data (with tabs as separators) (I assume the file was generated by a dump-program) and avoid editors that silently convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: Yes, these data were generated through command pg_dump but I don't have access for generate them. I'm trying to work with what I have at this moment. @wildplasser

Comment: pg_dump creates readable tab-separated output, so some editor must have screwed up... How large it is? for ~100, I'd edit it by hand... Otherwise, you should find a way to clean them up. The start of line is reasonably simple: two ints and a timstamp. The end of line is simple too: an int and a string without spaces. Wat rests is the large messagestring in the middle. Should be doable. BTW: I'd start by hexdumping the thing. maybe the tab->spaces conversion is only at a few places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below program will clean up the input data.

- It works on the two test lines in the question
- for larger input some additional tweaking may be needed.
- Take  care that no initial space is present at the beginning of lines.
- if performance is needed: make the functions static and they will get inlined.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
** cleantab.c: correct tab-separated dumpfile in which tabs have been expanded
** to spaces.
** input is from stdin; output goes to stdout.
** Note : space and tab in the input are seen as single whithespace,
** so multipe tabs *without* non whites betweesn them are merged into ones
** (for the Postgres .tsv file this could only happen on fields
** that originally were NULL)
** /

/** Test data
1       42  2015-03-13 12:12:13         wat the fuck &#sssdd  hiero </html> nog-een-string      13
2       442  2015-03-13 13:13:13        wat the sia uck &#nss    dd  daaro </html>kut nog-een-string    13
*/

char bigbuff[1024*1024];

struct witje {
        size_t off;
        size_t len;
        } witjes[16*1024];

size_t parse_line( char *str, struct witje *arr);
void dump_chunks(char *str, struct witje *arr,  size_t nwit);
void dump_nchar(char *str, size_t nchar);
void dump_nchar_notab(char *str, size_t nchar);

int main(void)
{
size_t nwit,iwit;

for ( ; fgets(bigbuff, sizeof bigbuff, stdin); ) {
        nwit = parse_line(bigbuff, witjes);

#if 0
        for (iwit = 0; iwit < nwit; iwit++ ) {
                fprintf(stderr,"[%zu] %zu+%zu\n"
                , iwit, witjes[iwit].off , witjes[iwit].len );
                }
#endif
        dump_chunks(bigbuff, witjes ,  nwit);
        }

return 0;
}
size_t parse_line( char *str, struct witje *arr)
{
size_t len, pos, idx;

for(len= pos= idx=0; str[pos]; pos += len) {
        arr[idx].off = pos;     /* position of whitespace */
        len = strspn(str+pos, " \t\n\r" );
        pos += len;
        arr[idx++].len = len;   /* length of whitespace */
        len = strcspn(str+pos, " \t\n\r" );
        }
return idx;
}

void dump_chunks(char *str, struct witje *arr,  size_t nwit)
{
size_t iwit, pos;

for ( pos= iwit = 0; iwit < nwit; iwit++ ) {
        // if (iwit ==0 && arr[iwit].off == 0 && arr[iwit].len ==0) { iwit++; nwit--; continue; }
        if (arr[iwit].off >pos) dump_nchar(str+pos, arr[iwit].off -pos);        /* payload */
        pos = arr[iwit].off ;
        if (arr[iwit].len) switch (iwit) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
                dump_nchar("\t", 1);    /* tab */
                break;
        case 3:
                dump_nchar(" ", 1);     /* the space  between date and time*/
                break;
        default:
                if (iwit == nwit -1) dump_nchar("\n", 1);       /* nl */
                else if (iwit >= nwit -3) dump_nchar("\t", 1);  /* tab */
                else dump_nchar_notab(str+pos, arr[iwit].len) ; /* whitespace */
                break;
                }
        pos += arr[iwit].len ;
        }
}

void dump_nchar(char *str, size_t nchar) {
while (nchar--) putc(*str++, stdout);
}

void dump_nchar_notab(char *str, size_t nchar) {
for ( ;nchar--; str++) putc(*str == '\t' ? ' ' : *str, stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know like but I solved with one strange command for situation:  GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA schema_name TO psql_roler_name. After I typed the restore command and worked fine. Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: Well, most probably the lines **preceding the ones you showed** created a schema and altered the search_path to it, but the current session was not allowed to use that particular schema.

Comment: The lines preceding have SET SEARCH_PATH command but don't have CREATE SCHEMA. They have one CREATE TABLE command too.